# How to install keras 1.2.2 in Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

Solving environment: ...working... failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- keras==1.2.2

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pip to install specific keras verion

```
pip install keras==1.2.2
```